# What is void[]?

Tags: d

I've seen the type `void[]` used in a few places in the D documentation and function signatures. What does it mean?

I've searched the array section in the documentation as well as Google, but didn't turn up anything conclusive. All I found is that all arrays are implicitly convertible to the `void[]` type. Is it just an untyped array?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`void[]` is just an array of anything. `in void[]` is a convenient signature for a function that just writes bytes to a file or something because it will accept any kind of array - `void` meaning the type isn't important and `in` meaning you aren't meaning to modify or store it, thus allowing you to accept const or immutable arrays too.

To use a `void[]`, you must first cast it to something else, typically, `ubyte[]`, so the elements have a concrete size allowing you to index it. `void[].length` is given as the total number of bytes in the array, so if you are just passing a pointer and length of data to a function (like an operating system level file write, e.g. Linux's `write` syscall), passing `arr.ptr, arr.length` will get those bytes written without caring about what they represent.

Comment: I should also mention the other kind of void you might see: `void*`, which means a pointer to anything. `void*` are common in C for the same kinds of things `void[]` is used for in D (and a bit more, C uses void* in some places D would use templates or classes/interfaces too - for generic data.) `void*` is also possible in D and is sometimes seen paired with a `TypeInfo` argument, allowing for runtime generics. Templates are usually better, but there's some parts of the D runtime library that uses the void* + TypeInfo pair instead (mostly for historical reasons). So you might see it there.